# does propensity score matching apply when the treament group was selected not naturally occuring?

Tags: propensity-scores

I think of propensity score matching as a method for finding a comparison group for  a naturally occurring group like students who attend private school.

But if you have a group that was selected for an intervention (not randomly) but by application does it make sense to use propensity scores to find a comparison group?
Also an entire organization was selected not individual students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use propensity score methods in a variety of settings. The appropriateness of the methods depends on having a good set of observed covariates that measure the potential sources of confounding. A setting where the intervention is selected by an application could be fine provided you still have controls available who based on their covariate values could have received the intervention. The propensity score methods would not be appropriate when 1) you don't have important sources of confounding observed and/or 2) the covariate distributions for one or more important covariates do not overlap between the intervention and control groups. That problem 2 could happen when an application selected who got the intervention based on important covariates. For more, see the positivity assumption for propensity scores in the literature.

Comment: So the fact there was some experimentation done and the groups are not purely observational is ok?

Comment: Yes. For example, a great setting for using a propensity score method like inverse probability of treatment weighting is a randomized trial with non-trivial imbalance in important covariates due to an unlucky randomization.